# Tryton Incompatible version of the server

Tags: ubuntu-11.10, erp, tryton

I'm trying to connect Tryton to a postgres database. In the Tryton client profile, I used the following details:

- Hostname : localhost
- port : 8000
- username : admin

Now everytime I put in the details above, the database labels show:

```
Incompatible version of the server
```

So I check out Tryton server and client version and I found out its:

```
tryton = 2.6.0
trytond = 2.0.1
```

Ok, now I know that the trytond is not the same as my tryton version.
I have searched the web many times to find a matching client and server version but failed.

Even in Ubuntu synaptic package manager, I can't find a real same version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the same two first version number. So you must use 2.6 series or 2.0 series.
On Ubuntu, [last series packaged](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=tryton) is 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip)? If not, then install it first. This is the best tool(in my knowledge) to install python packages.

To install tryton client using pip `sudo pip install 'tryton>2.6,<2.7'` and for tryton server `sudo pip install 'trytond>2.6,<2.7'`. This will install both tryton client and server of latest series 2.6. To install different version just change the version number in command.

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

you can download the tryton and and corresponding trytond versions from   http://downloads.tryton.org/2.6/